# Why does my double pointer overwrite its rows?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I am trying to input one char at a time to each block per row, but what happens is the latest row will overwrite the previous content I stored in the previous row. In the end, all my rows have the same content.. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int row=0,col=0,i;
    char c;
    char **this=NULL;

    this=calloc(64,sizeof(char*));


    for(i=0;i<64;++i)
    {
        this[i]=calloc(5,sizeof(char));
        free(this[i]);
    }

    while(c!=EOF)
    {
        c=getchar();
        if(!isspace(c)&&isprint(c))
        {
            if(c==',')
            {
                this[row][col]='\0';
                row++;
                col=0;
            }
            else if(c=='.')
            {
                this[row][col]=c;
                this[row][col+1]='\0';
            }
            else 
            {
            this[row][col]=c;
            //printf("%d,%d\n",row, col);
            //printf("%c\n",this[row][col]);
            //printf("%s\n",this[row]);
            //printf("%s\n",this[row+1]);
            col++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("string0:%s\n",this[0]);//prints the same thing
    printf("string1:%s\n",this[1]);

    free(this);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What's up with the `free(this[i])` right after allocating? Your usage of any of the pointers after that is undefined behavior.

Comment: I know whenever I allocate, I need to free it so I can still reuse the space? but I dont really know where I should free it.

Comment: You free the memory when you're done with it. If you try to use the allocated memory (and the pointer object as well) after free, it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: If I'd have to guess why you're seeing what you're seeing, I'd say that the subsequent calls to `calloc()` return the same area over and over since you're freeing just before. But it is pointless to try and explain undefined behavior, because it is *undefined*.

Comment: Also: `char c;` -->> `int c;` (but the EOF logic is still wrong)

Answer (score 2):

In your code, after `calloc()`-ing, you immediately do

```
 free(this[i]);
```

making the memory to be marked as *released* (i.e., not to be used anymore). Then, later you try to use the memory, it causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You have to free the memory once you're done using it. A good time to call `free()` on individual `this[i]` will be right before the

```
  free(this);
```

call.

Comment: ohhhh tyty its fixedd!